# Turn off any IntelliSense, compiler notices and warnings, and suggestions in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, resharper, suppress-warnings

I need to present a C# application's code as part of a presentation and it must be presented in the IDE itself. Thus, I want to disable any IntelliSense / compiler notices / warnings / code suggestions that might pop up mid-presentation, leaving only color coding.

For example, I do not wish dotted green and blue lines under fields like so:

[image]

How can I turn those off, and how can I turn them back on after presentation?

*(Note: I use resharper for C#.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no *easy* way to fully disable IntelliSense in Visual Studio. However, you *can* turn off (most of) those features that you want to hide.

For example, to prevent the display of those squiggles (for errors and warnings), use the following.

From the "Tools" menu, select "Options." In the pop-up, open the "Text Editor" node in the left-hand window and select the "General" sub-option. Then, in the right-hand pane, uncheck the "Show error squiggles" box.

[image]

You can disable/enable (many) other 'annoying' features in a similar manner, although finding where to do so is not always trivial. Remember to look also in the "All Languages" and "C#" sub-nodes (in the left-hand pane) for other features to disable/enable.

Comment: Why not just fix the problems that Intellisense is finding? That is by far the easiest way to get rid of the squiggles and warning messages.

Comment: @DaveHolden But, quite often, IntelliSense finds problems that aren't there. (At least, in C and C++, it does - I use C# far less often, so my experience with that is more limited.) Also, OP may want to demonstrate something that is a "work in progress" but without the warnings displayed for the whole world to see.

Comment: @DaveHolden Intellisense complains when I use "fieldName" over "_fieldName", even tho this method of writing has been ditched from official docs long ago, and more nonsensical suggestions. If it was only compiler warning, so be it. but when its   Intellisense then some really bad stuff can get suggested. this is why it's a suggestion and not a warning.